# sublista en python

Tags: python, lista

quiero hacer en python una sublista con la siguiente característica: primeramente tengo una lista con estos elementos

```
lista = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

y crear la siguiente sublista:

```
lista_2 = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10))
```

Es posible hacerlo en python?
Necesito el algoritmo para una app en Django.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cual es el criterio? Crear tuplas de tres elementos y la última con los que sobren?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un generador que vaya devolviendo los elementos de tu iterable de `n` en `n`, mientras haya suficientes, y que cuando ya no haya suficientes devuelva los que han sobrado

```py
def grouper(iterable, n):
     i=0
     while i<len(iterable)-n:
        yield tuple(iterable[i:i+n])
        i+=n
     yield tuple(iterable[i:])
```

Puedes usarlo en tu caso así (hacemos `n=3`)

```py
lista = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
lista_2 = tuple(grouper(lista, 3))
```

El resultado en `lista2` será:

```
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10,))
```

Comment: Gracias! estoy aprendiendo python y me encuentro con que hay funciones que no conozco en profundidad (como yield por ejemplo). Funciona perfecto y es justo lo que necesitaba para mi proyecto web.

Comment: @Agughost `yield` es típico en la implementación de generadores, que son como funciones que van retornando datos "uno a uno" (en cada `yield`). Estas funciones puedes usarlas luego en un bucle `for` como yo he hecho. De todas formas ya has visto que hay más formas de resolverlo. La solución de Chema usa una _expresión generadora_, que no usa `yield` y es aún más breve. Para este caso es más adecuada que mi solución. Otros casos más complejos pueden requerir escribir un generador al "no caber" en una expresión generadora.

Answer (score 3):

Algo simple:

```
lista_2 = tuple(lista[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(lista),3))
```

---

**Editado:**

En la documentación del módulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) vienen algunas recetas, entre las que se encuentra una función `grouper` que hace una agrupación genérica de elementos:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Aplicado a la pregunta original, se podría ver así:

```
it = [iter(lista)] * 3
lista_2 = [list(group) for group in zip_longest(*it)]
```

O si quiere, más explícitamente:

```
it = iter(lista)
lista_2 = [list(group) for group in zip_longest(it, it, it)]
```

El truco consiste en que `zip_longest` llama tres veces al iterador `it`, devolviendo sus tres primeros elementos que formarán la terna, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Tendrías que poner lista_2 o lista2, sino dará error

Comment: Gracias! Necesitaba la función para ordenar imágenes que muestra la vista de la app que estoy desarrollando en Django. Abrazo!

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Rectificado.

Answer (score 0):

Gente, gracias a los algoritmos que publicaron deje el codigo asi:

```
def agrupar(lista, n):
    i = 0
    list = [] #Lista
    while(i < len(lista)):
        list.append(lista[i:i+n])
        i += n
    return tuple(list)

lista = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

lista_2 = agrupar(lista, 3)
print(lista_2)
```